# How to check if user already exists firebase with React js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-redux

I am using signInPopup method and want to check if the user already exists in firebase with the email and if exists want to redirect to home and if not want to redirect to other homepage .

```
     

  const googleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
            signInWithPopup(auth, googleAuthProvider).then(async function (user) 
            {
                
            if(user!=user.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser)
            {
                navigate("/k")
            }
            else
            {
                navigate("/p")
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `isNewUser` is a boolean.

So change your if condition to:

```js
if(user.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
  // it's a new user
} else {
  // user already known
}
```

Also read: [AdditionalUserInfo#isNewUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo#public-abstract-boolean-isnewuser)

Comment: its giving error like its not going in if else

Comment: Is your syntax correct? As far as I see you're missing a `})` for your `async function`.

Comment: try {

            const googleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
            signInWithPopup(auth, googleAuthProvider).then((user)=> 
            {    
            if(user.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser)
            {
                console.log("new user")
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("already a user")
            }
            
             
            }).catch((error)=>{
                console.log("error")
            })








        }
        catch (error) {
            setError(error.message)
        }

Comment: You should investigate the error object like this: `console.log("error", error)`

Comment: i have done signin with email and password now i want to check that when user logins with google that the user is new user so redirect to other page and if old user redirect to home page

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isNewUser')

Comment: Use `debugger` one line before the if-else and investigate the `user` object, if it looks as expected.

Comment: nothing happened